# What global health organization coordinates vaccine production?

Tags: covid-19

## Question

What, if any,  global health organization coordinates global vaccine production?

## Context:

It is in the global interest to produce qualified (safety / efficacy) COVID-19 vaccine doses as quick as possible to arrest and reverse the pandemic.

As I understand the matter:

1. Global vaccine production capacity is finite
2. Pfizer, Moderna, Astra-Zeneca vaccines require 2 doses: JNJ = 1dose
3. Some vaccines do not have phase 3 trials (Sputnik)
4. [Operation Warp Speed](https://www.hhs.gov/coronavirus/explaining-operation-warp-speed/index.html) coordinates a US effort
5. Other Global vaccine producers include Cansino (CA-CN), J&J, Samsung Biologics (KR)

It would seem that there is an opportunity for production sites to coordinate with a single body to coordinate production to optimize safety/efficacy/speed in a global context.

Comment: Are you asking if such an organization exists or just advocating for it? Also, Pfizer had nothing to do with Operation Warp Speed so I don't think you can say it's coordinating anything.

Comment: @CareyGregory.  Thanks for the question.  I have update the post to clarify.  ["Pfizer has been working with U.S. officials in Operation Warp Speed (OWS) and the U.S. Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC)"](https://www.pfizer.com/news/press-release/press-release-detail/pfizer-update-our-us-covid-19-vaccine-candidate)

Comment: I don't know what "working with" means in concrete terms but Pfizer took no money from the OWS program and developed the vaccine entirely on their own. I just think it's a bit of a reach to say OWS is coordinating the US vaccine effort. I think the CDC is really the agency doing all the coordinating.

Answer (score 4):

No one coordinates global vaccine production. Vaccines, like other pharmaceuticals, are produced by individual companies. Individual companies have been entering into agreements with individual governments to deliver vaccine for the residents of their countries.

The Bill and Melinda Gates foundation has made [GAVI](https://www.gavi.org/) (along with partners in the WHO and UNICEF) as a [public-private partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAVI) to do something like maybe what you are thinking of as coordination to try to ensure poorer countries have vaccine access, and they now have a Covid-19 vaccination program, but this is really just an effort to combine resources among those that have the fewest resources. They don't have any say over what other countries do.